# Expresso Store: Display price including tax from channel:entries tag

Tags: expresso-store

First Store project underway for a UK store charging VAT.

I'm (probably) going to enter prices ex-VAT into the database as they do ship internationally, but I generally want to display them inc-VAT throughout the site. The only place I'm likely to split things out is in the checkout.

Is there a "best practice" for this? I've got my VAT setup and UK is the default country, but I can't figure out how to add tax to the price displayed using a {store_field:price} tag.

Quite happy to get my hands dirty with add-ons/extensions etc, but not if I don't have to.

thanks

Comment: See my answer [here](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18220/display-store-product-prices-excluding-tax/18243#18243) as to why this is a bad idea

Comment: ok, that's going to take some digesting! But I'm already encountering rounding issues so I suspect you're right

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue so wrote a [Tax plugin](https://github.com/peteralewis/tax), I've just uploaded it but still needs instructions adding.

**Template Tags** - either as tag pairs or single tags:

- {exp:tax:only} - display only the tax
- {exp:tax:price} - display the price with tax
- {exp:tax:none} - display the non-taxed price

If using as single tags, use the value or price parameter to set the numerical price value. Value passed can already be inclusive or exclusive of tax - default is that tax is already included in price.

**Example**:

1. {exp:tax:only value="10" rate="20" currency="£" show_currency="yes"}
2. {exp:tax:only rate="20" currency="£" show_currency="yes"}10{/exp:tax:only}

Will both output: £2.00

**Parameters**:

- included (is the tax already included in the passed price value)
- value or price (the number/string to use - for single tags only)
- rate (rate of tax, any non numerical characters will be stripped)
- show_currency (show the currency symbol on output - defaults to no)
- currency (what currency symbol to use - can also take any character passed as a value or  within the tag pair)
- position (where the currency symbol should appear, options are "before" and "after" - defaults to before)
- decimals (show decimal points - defaults to yes)
- thousands (show the thousands character - defaults to yes, character can only be defined through config settings)
- rounding (how the calculations should be rounded, options are "up", "down", "nearest")

All the above defaults can be defined in the EE config file:

- tax_rate
- tax_included
- tax_currency
- tax_position
- tax_decimals
- tax_thousands
- tax_show_currency
- tax_rounding
- tax_decimal_places
- tax_thousand_symbol
- tax_decimal_symbol

Decimal places, decimal character and thousand character can only be set via config variables.